# MATLAB Error - Undefined function or method 'fitcsvm' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I am running

```
SVMModel = fitcsvm(X,Y,'KernelFunction','rbf','Standarize',true,'ClassNames',[-1,1]);
```

and the error I get is

```
Undefined function or method 'fitcsvm' for input arguments of type 'double'
```

I am pretty sure X and Y are matrices though:

```
size(X)
ans =
544    28


size(Y)
ans =
544     1
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a function available in Matlab 2014 alone as of now. Check your version of matlab and statistical tool box you have.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that there is no such function. Since the function is part of the Machine Learning Toolbox, it is very likely you don't own this toolbox. Look for it using the `ver` command in you command window.